# How to put a PROPER conditional expression in a height of container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to code this: `Container(height: _key.currentState!.validate() ? 417 : 480,`

but I got an error:

> Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: it means that `_key.currentState` for some reason is `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pskink said in the comment, `_key.currentState` is `null` for some reason. You could, depending on your needs, do something like this:

```
Container(height: _key.currentState?.validate() == true ? 417 : 480,
```

Comment: Tnx! bros, appreciated